# No me trae ningún resultado

Tags: php, sql-server-2012

**Colocando la sentencia en sql server si me arroja resultado pero cuando intento recorrer en el php no me muestra ningún resultado y me devuelve false**
**procedimiento almacenado SQLserver**

```
insert into #fte_contacto_anual 
        select a.cod_lead, a.nom_lead, a.ced_lead, a.email_lead, a.telf_lead, a.st_lead, 
        a.fecha_creacion, a.hora_creacion, a.cod_usuario, a.cod_empresa, a.cod_usuario_asignado,
        a.genero, a. campaingid, a.st_comercializar,  a.cod_oferta_academica, a.cod_fuente_contacto, a.cod_medio_gestion,
        CASE

            WHEN FORMAT(a.fecha_creacion,'MM') = '05'  THEN 'Mayo'

        ELSE
            'Sin Gestionar'
        END AS nom_mes,
        ISNULL(g.color, '#41a940' ) AS color_fuente,
        ISNULL(g.nom_fuente_contacto, 'Desconocido')AS fuente_contacto
        from leads AS a
        LEFT JOIN perfil as f ON a.cod_usuario_asignado = f.cod_perfil
        LEFT JOIN oferta_academica AS b ON b.cod_oferta_academica = a.cod_oferta_academica
        LEFT JOIN leads_fuente_contacto AS g ON a.cod_fuente_contacto = g.cod_fuente_contacto 
        LEFT JOIN directorio as directorio ON directorio.cod_directorio = a.cod_directorio
        LEFT JOIN leads_medios_gestion AS i ON i.cod_medio_gestion = a.cod_medio_gestion
        WHERE a.st_lead!='X' AND a.cod_empresa ='2' 


    if(@tipo_consulta = 'meses_leads')
            BEGIN
                          set @query = 'select  pa.fuente_contacto, pa.color_fuente,

                          sum(CASE WHEN pa.nom_mes = ''Mayo'' THEN  1 ELSE 0 END) AS may

                          from #fte_contacto_anual pa  WHERE nom_lead != ''''  ' + @filtros + ' 
                          group by pa.fuente_contacto, pa.color_fuente
                          order by pa.fuente_contacto, pa.color_fuente'
                           EXEC (@query);
            END
        END
```

**y en mi php me devuelve false en la parte sqlsrv_fetch_array($ObtenidosAnuales), en la conexion si lo hace bien, solo es en la parte de recorrer no se si es devido de la creacion del procedimiento almacenado  **

```
$sql = "{call lead_estadisticos(?,?)}";
                                    $params = array("meses_leads", $condicionusuario);
                                    $ObtenidosAnuales = sqlsrv_query($conexion, $sql, $params);
                                    $dataPoints = array();
                                    $aux = array();

                                     while ($fila = sqlsrv_fetch_array($ObtenidosAnuales)) {
                                             $fila['may'];
                                    }
```

**no encuentro el problema**

Answer (score 0):

Ya me paso una vez, así que creo que la solucion es facil, solamente coloca en el procedimiento almacenado `SET NOCOUNT ON`, basicamente lo que hace es desactivar ese mensaje que vez luego de un update/delete en el que dice `(100 filas afectadas)`, el primer resultado que viene en el `sqlsrv_fetch_array` al ejecutar un SP es la cantidad de filas afectadas (cuando no tiene el `SET NOCOUNT ON`) , por eso no te muestra resultados. Espero te sirva.